# Finding a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am currently studying for my first exam in my second course of abstract algebra and cannot seem to understand the reasoning in the following explanation. In finding a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}$, why are we able to state in computing the factor ring (in the following picture) that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side? I guess i’m not understanding how that type of computation is possible.

> Let $\mathbb{Z}\times 3\mathbb{Z}$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Then compute the factor ring
>   $$\begin{align*}
> (\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z}\times 3\mathbb{Z}) &\cong (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\\
> &\cong \{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_3\\
> &\cong \mathbb{Z}_3
> \end{align*}$$
>   Since $3$ is a prime number, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field, and hence the factor ring $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z}\times 3\mathbb{Z})$ is a field.

Comment: Put differently, "clearly" the kernel of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+3\Bbb Z$ is precisely $3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following lemma solves your question:

**Lemma**: Let $R,S$ be rings and $I$ an ideal of $R$ and $J$ an ideal of $S$. Then

$$(R\times S)/(I \times J) \cong R/I \times S/J$$

**Proof**: Define a map $\psi: R \times S \to R/I \times S/J: (r,s) \mapsto (r+I, s+J)$. Clearly this is a surjection with kernel $I \times J$ and the isomorphism follows from the first isomorphism theorem of rings. $\quad \square$

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. Where did you find this lemma?

Comment: It is just a straightforward application of the first isomorphism theorem. I added a proof.

Comment: Sorry just one more question: if we are referencing the first isomorphism theorem, don’t we need to know what the image is?

Comment: Also, is $\mathbb{Z}$ an ideal of itself?

Comment: Yes, we know what the image is because the map I wrote down is a surjection. Thus the image is equal to the codomain. And yes, any ring is an ideal of itself. The ideal definition is satisfied trivially.

Comment: Thank you for your time! This cleared up my concerns.

Comment: If this answer helped, you may consider accepting it, letting others know your question is solved.